# Show that $\arg(\exp(z)) = y + 2\pi k$ for any $\arg(\exp(z))$ and some integer $k$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The entire question is:
Show that $\operatorname{mod}(\exp(z)) = e^x$. Show that $\arg(\exp(z)) = y + 2\pi k$ for any $\arg(\exp(z))$ and some integer $k$.

I could do the first part. I do not know how to do the second.
**Guidance please.**

Comment: What is that $\,y\,$ there?

Comment: @DonAntonio $z = x + iy$

Comment: Are you familiar with (one of the many) Euler's formula?

Comment: @DanielFischer Never heard. What do they do ? :)

Comment: Solve your problem, if you pick the right one ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Now now now .. How many formulae does he have ?

Comment: $\aleph_\omega$, approximately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i know if $z '=x '+iy'$ then $\arg(z ')=\arctan(\frac{y '}{x '})$
$$exp(z)=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x\cos(y)+ie^x\sin(y)=x '+iy'$$
$$\arg(exp(z))=\arctan(\frac{y '}{x '})=\arctan(\frac{e^x\sin(y)}{e^x \cos(y)})=\arctan(tan(y))=y+2k\pi \color{red}{\Rightarrow}$$$$\color{green}{\arg(\exp(z)) = y + 2\pi k}$$

Comment: Is it the same as this ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Number#Absolute_value_and_argument

Comment: Is it always true that $\arg z = \arctan \frac {y } {x } $? What if $x<0 $ for instance?